# Switch conditionally between client and server resolvers with @client directive

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, gql

I need to be able to use server resolvers in development env, but in all other evs, I want to use the client resolvers. I was checking if there is an elegant way to skip the @client directive in development.

For now, it seems that the simplest is to wrap the query that is passed into `gql` with a custom function that would remove the default @client directive.

Comment: I solved it with a simple helper function
`allEvents(filter: $filter) ${toggleClientDirective()} { ...}`
which based on a condition returns either `@client` or ""